# Why does Thunderbird hang when I try to quit it?

Tags: mac, osx-snow-leopard, thunderbird

I'm running Thunderbird 3.1.7 under Snow Leopard, and whenever I try to quit Thunderbird it just hangs there and never actually quits till I force quit it. Any one know why it's doing this?

Comment: Have you got Enigmail installed?

Comment: Same issue, same OS, no Enigmail.

Comment: No I don't have Enigmail.

Comment: Same issue, same OS, no Enigmail here, as well

Comment: Same issue with latest Thunderbird (5.0) but have had the problem for the last 6 months or more with older versions. Nearly every time I quite Thunderbird it hangs and needs to be force quit. Running OSX Snow Leopard. Connecting to a large IMAP account (on Dreamhost), a gmail account (via IMAP) and an exchange server (via IMAP).